# tf.keras.models.model vs tf.keras.model

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2

Is the `models` redundant in tf.keras API? For some cases, even without using `models`, the code also runs well.

1. `keras.models.sequential` and `keras.sequential`
2. `tf.keras.models.Model` and `tf.keras.Model`

However, sometimes, `models` seems to be necessary. For example,
`model = keras.models.load_model()`, But `model = keras.Model` does not has `.load_model()` function. Because `.load_model()` is defined in `tf.keras.Model`.

I find it quite confusing and semi-redundant. Could anyone explain what is the point of `models`, and when it is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a little more intuitive and easier to read (though admittedly it depends on the accuracy of the documentation). Using the [TensorFlow documentation](http://This%20is%20with%20**TensorFlow%202.3.0**%20but%20should%20be%20similar%20for%20other%20prior%202.x%20versions.), you can click on "view aliases" as I've done here in the below screenshot:

[image]

this will show that `tf.keras.Model` has `tf.keras.models.Model` as an alias. Therefore, they point to the same thing.

This is with **TensorFlow 2.3.0** but should be similar for other prior 2.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

they are the same thing. all is   `from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training import Model`
checkout:
[keras.**init**.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py) and
[keras.models.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py%3Ekeras.models.py)